# how to get specific value in list with many elements c# list

Tags: c#, list

how can i get the value of name only in the list. Thanks

```
List<windowsteam> _windowsList = new List<windowsteam>();
_windowsList.Add(new windowsteam {name = "John Smith", bei= "john.smith" });
_windowsList.Add(new windowsteam { name = "John Bau", bei = "john.bau",});
```

Comment: What exactly you need?

Comment: You want a list of names from the `_windowsList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 List<string> lstNames = new List<string>();

 foreach(windowsteam ws in _windowsList)
 { 
      lstNames.Add(ws.name);
 }
```

Above code should get value of name only in the list.

Here is code below if you want to find `windowsteam` object by its name. For specific name you should expect an object in the return.

**Example** (Returning `windowsteam` object having name `John Bau`):

```
windowsteam ws = _windowsList.Find(a => a.name == "John Bau");
```

There is `FindAll` option also available for `List` collection. You could find all objects of `windowsteam` in a List having name starting with certain characters.

**Example** (Getting all those `windowsteam` object having name starting with `John`):

```
List<windowsteam> lstFound = _windowsList.FindAll(a => a.name.StartsWith("John"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = _windowsList.Select(w => w.name).ToList();
```

Comment: should be lower case *n* in `name`

Comment: Don't forget to assign it to a variable, it doesn't alter the original `_windowsList` :)

Comment: what if i will use it in if to compare?

Answer (score 1):

To get all names...

```
List<string> names = _windowsList.Select(p => p.name).ToList();
```

Edit based on comment, this will get you the full record

```
 var singlewindowsList = _windowsList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.name == "John Bau");
```

or this will get you the name only...

```
var nameOnly = _windowsList.Where(p => p.name == "John Bau").Select(p => p.name)
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will work, but slightly irrelevant?

Comment: what if i will use it in if to compare?

Comment: @user3721685 , give an example of **compare**?

Comment: the select is underlined red

Comment: make sure you have `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @eirawn, where is the `If` check in the accepted answer, and what version of the framework are you using?